# web reference does not view in VS2010 solution explrorer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-services

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and TFS 2010.
I have got some web services that exist in the solution folder but they do not appear in the solution explorer Web References. I re-add the web Service reference with the name used in the code but it does add a "1" in the end, showing that it exists in the solution. how can I add it to the solution as I can call it in the code?

P.S. I should mention I can delete the previous one and add the reference again, but as I have plenty of services to call it is not somehow logic and it is time consuming.

thanks in advance,

Comment: @Rachel Yes, I did. but no changes.

Comment: @Rachel I should confirm that refresh works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Rachel mentioned, refresh works fine.